# Does EXCHANGE statement on Atomic engine provide atomic capabilities for multiple tables?

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

[Documentation declares Atomicity](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/exchange) for exchanging two tables, but what about multiple tables? Following query works well and perform exchanging within tables `A <=> B` and `C <=> D`:

```
EXCHANGE TABLES "default"."A" AND "default"."B", "default"."C" AND "default"."D"
```

Does EXCHANGE statement on Atomic engine provide atomic capabilities for multiple tables?
Can be situation when `A <=> B` exchanged but `C <=> D` not? Does atomicity spreads on whole EXCHANGE query?

Answer (score 2):

They are not atomic.

```sql
insert into a.x1 select 1;
insert into a.x1 select 2;

exchange tables a.x1 and a.x2, a.y1 and a.y2;

Received exception from server (version 22.6.1):
Code: 521. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000.DB::ErrnoException: Paths cannot be exchanged because /var/lib/clickhouse/store/209/209474d2-5d64-4ca0-8b45-9abf4109235a/y1.sql or /var/lib/clickhouse/store/209/209474d2-5d64-4ca0-8b45-9abf4109235a/y2.sql does not exist, errno: 2, strerror: No such file or directory. (ATOMIC_RENAME_FAIL)

select * from a.x1;
Ok.
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.


select * from a.x2
┌─A─┐
│ 2 │
└───┘
┌─A─┐
│ 1 │
└───┘
```

Atomicy is not about DML transactions. It's about visibility for selects. That queries do not see intermediate state and do not throw `table . does not exists...`

Comment: In your example, the error is created in a forced way by accessing obviously non-existent tables. In principle, it is clear that operations are performed from left to right until the first error. However, this is more atomic than just sending multiple EXCHANGE requests from the client. Because the HTTP connection can break at any time, and here the server makes a single request.